# fe_sendauth: no password supplied error with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am working on a new RoR app, and I keep recieving fe_sendauth: no password supplied when creating a new database. I have tried installing and reinstalling postgresql with no change.

```
Eric-Parks-MacBook-Pro:dearMe ericpark$ rake db:create
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:567:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each_current_configuration'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"dearMe_development"}
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:567:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each_current_configuration'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"dearMe_test"}
Eric-Parks-MacBook-Pro:dearMe ericpark$
```

database.yml

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 8.2 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On OS X with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On OS X with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: dearMe_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
  #username: dearMe

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  #password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: dearMe_test

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: dearMe_production
  username: dearMe
  password: <%= ENV['DEARME_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

I believe I can set the password and username up within the database.yml, but what would I set them as?

Answer (score 1):

You **MUST** add a password to your database, your database.yml should look something like this

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  host: localhost
  adapter: postgresql
  database: databasename
  user: papinotas
  port: 5432
  password: databasepassword

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: Hi Waclock,   How do I know what the database password is? Is that already preset? Or do I set it within the database.yml?

Comment: You must first create it when you create the database using psql (or any other postgres console)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `password` into your `database.yml`

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
```

You can use the default password or create another one [here](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/cloud/amazon/change-default-database-passwords-on-linux.htm).